# Mirror from GitLab to Notabug reporting error

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a few mirrors setup from GitLab to various Git hosts and they work fine.  However, when I try to setup a mirror from GitLab to Notabug.org, GitLab shows the following error:

13:push to mirror: git push: exit status 1, stderr: "error: RPC failed; HTTP 401 curl 22 The Requested URL returned error: 401\nsend-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet\nfatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly\nEverything up-to-date\n".

When I create the mirror on GitLab, I use this as the push URL:

```
https://notabug.org/username/repo.git
```

For password, I enter my Notabug password.  I don't want to use SSH.

I have tried creating a completely blank repository on Notabug and I have also tried initialising it with a readme file.  But I get the above error when I try to mirror from GitLab to Notabug.

I don't have Git installed locally since it's not needed.

Thank you.

Comment: No replies at all.  I did some research and someone said that using SSH resolved this issue for them but I don't know how to use SSH with Notabug.  Someone else said increasing the Git buffer size but I can't do that when mirroring from GitLab to Notabug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in [`notabug.org/fingerprints`](https://notabug.org/fingerprints), an SSH URL for a notabug repository would be:

```
 git clone git@notabug.org:my-user/my-project.git
```

Check your Gogs-based/notabug user account settings to register your public key.

That is assuming notabug is still active:

- its fork of Gogs ([`notabug.org/hp/gogs`](https://notabug.org/hp/gogs)) has not been updated since 2018
- its [outage page](https://notabug.org/outages) has not been updated since 2016
- its [issue page](https://notabug.org/hp/gogs/issues) is... 404

---

Following "[GitLab / Repository mirroring / SSH public key authentication](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html#ssh-public-key-authentication)":

- GitLab does generate a private key
- you copy the public key on the remote side.

Said public key is accessed with the `Copy SSH public key` button:

[image: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/img/repository_mirroring_copy_ssh_public_key_button.png]

From the [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236061/discussion-between-vonc-and-jstation), this worked.

Comment: As I said, I'm trying to create a mirror in GitLab.  The only URL that works for the mirror is ssh://git@notabug.org/username/repo.git.  With this URL, GitLab does detect the keys automatically.  But when I add the mirror, it reports an error 'Permission denied: Could not read from remote repository, make sure you have the correct access rights'.  So maybe I'm registering the wrong key in Notabug.  The key I'm registering in Notabug is from an online SSH keygen site: https://8gwifi.org/sshfunctions.jsp and in the name field I put ssh-rsa and then paste the key in the contents field.

Comment: @Jstation If the URL is correct, but GitLab still display the error message, it could be because it does not find the right private key to use. Did you register that key? How do you indicate GitLab for that mirroring setting that it should use that private key?

Comment: Like I said, I'm new to SSH, I don't really know about it.  I was hoping I didn't have to use it.  What do you suggest?

Comment: I mean, I can use that website linked above to get a fingerprint, public and private key, but what do I do with them?  I imagine I need to enter the public key (or is it the private one) on Notabug but it's asking for key name and content.  What do I put there?  And on GitLab, it's asking for host key.  Is that public key?

Comment: In GitLab, I added the public key to my account and when I created the mirror, I was given the option of using that key.  So I selected that option - to use that key for the mirror.  In Notabug, I added the same key to my Notabug account.  But I still see Permission denied when I try to start the mirror process from GitLab to Notabug.  Do I need to put the private key somewhere?  Or do anything with fingerprints?

Comment: @Jstation Can you share a screenshot of your GitLab settings for that mirror?

Comment: Not really but I can tell you:  Git repository URL is ssh://git@notabug.org/username/repo.git, when I click Detect Keys in GitLab then it finds and detects the keys automatically so the URL appears to be right, mirror direction is PUSH and authentication method is SSH public key.  That's it.  For the public key, I enter the one I made from the website.  For Notabug side, I add a new SSH key with an ID of id_rsa.pub and use my public key.  So the same public key is now on GitLab and Notabug.  I haven't used the private key at all though.  Do I need to use that?

Comment: @Jstation Yes, GitLab needs the private key if it wants to access the remote repository.

Comment: Do you know how I can add the private key to GitLab?  If I go to SSH Keys in GitLab, it has an option to add a public key.  It says 'Do not paste your private SSH key, as that can compromise your identity.'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236061/discussion-between-vonc-and-jstation).

Comment: Thanks, VonC.  I now realise that I need to copy the SSH key over to Notabug using the Copy SSH key button in GitLab mirror settings.  It works noe.